# Can't get to per-site metas from the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, ios-app

I'd like to be able to easily browse the per-site metas of some sites. Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to do this from the iOS app.

I tried searching for 'meta' in the other site chooser gizmo, but only mSO showed up. I've also tried tapping random likely-looking images and text. No luck.

Eventually, I found that I can do this by scrolling through my inbox and finding a notification from the meta I want to visit. I tap on it, then hit the back button. I can then see the meta's question list.

Can we please make this easier?

Comment: If you tap the little Up Down ↑↓ arrow next to the search bar it lets you see the meta sites.  The lack of metas in the list by default makes sense in that it reflects the site behavior, but then doesn't it provide any other good mechanism.

Comment: @Brian I might suggest making the title tappable when viewing a site's questions - I.e. tapping Super User in the nav bar when viewing SU question would bring up a menu thing where you can switch to meta. Seems like that would be better than having it under a sort-looking button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some small changes in the upcoming build which should make things a bit better.

1. When you open the site list, you will now see a header with "Main Sites" which should hopefully indicate that there's more you can do (mirroring the behavior of the question listing).
2. When you go into search, it will switch into "All Sites" mode which will find both main and meta sites.

**Update**

Got a Meta you visit all the time?  With the next build you can add it to the menu with Pinned Sites, a feature already in the Android app.

[image: Meta in the menu, edit button in the corner]

Comment: +1 for freehand yellow... uhm... things.

Comment: You look a little too young for being interested in the beer site ;P