# Provide a link to per-site Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, per-site-meta

The iOS app has no convenient way to get from a main site to its Meta. You have to go to the full site list and search for the specific Meta you want.

Could a link be provided somewhere? My first thought would be for a tap or tap-and-hold on the site name at the top of the Questions tab to pop up a "menu" with a link to the Meta (see the Taskpaper iOS app for this behavior). The Meta should likewise provide a link back to Main.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sooo... I was coming here to close the issue because this will be in the next build:

> [image: Screenshot showing Meta and Chat contextual menu options in menu]

But I liked Chris's answer so much I implemented it too:

> [image: Screenshot showing More tab with meta and chat links]

Long screenshots short:

- The fastest way to get to a per-site meta from a site in your left side menu is to simply long press the site and tap "Meta".
- The most discoverable way to get to a per-site meta (and probably the easiest if you're already looking at the site) is to tap on the "More" tab and then select "Switch to meta site".

I'll probably stash a few extra actions in the more tab like a quicker "Pin to menu" since that's not very convenient for a site you're already on.

Comment: Awesomeness in its best!

Comment: And 'open chat' too?! I feel spoilt! :-D thank you!

Comment: @Chris it just goes to the browser and it'll probably take you to the wrong URL until the app redownloads the site list in 0 to 24 hours.

Comment: @BrianNickel that by itself is a big help - I was always scrolling through my inbox to my last chat notification to get there! Cheers!

Comment: Is there an ETA for when this is coming [to Android](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223092/201409)? :)

Answer (score 6):

I agree this could be a lot better. Some changes were made in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221022/233816), but it still requires the user to 'set this up' - and I would have considered this a regularly used enough feature to not require that.

I think the best solution could be to add a link to the remarkably empty looking 'more' menu. I'd see it as fitting quite well alongside a link to your per-site profile.

[image: more menu]