# Can ios-app questions be retagged with android-app if the post applies to both? (And vice versa)

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the other *-app tag be added to a question that applies to both apps?

What is the recommended course of action for an issue that is present in both apps?

- Tag with both tags
- Ask separate identical (except for the tags) questions for both
- Something else?

Example: [Provide a link to per-site Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229369/180276) and many many more

Comment: *this* discussion question could probably be tagged ios-app and android-app :)

Comment: haha, yes it could, @mhlester!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it may be best to keep them separate, primarily because there are separate developers working on each, and so a combined question would make the status tags confusing.

Unless, perhaps, there's something really broad. I can't think of anything off the top of my head, there... but I can imagine it's *possible*.

Comment: They've expressed they want them separated several times. They're different operating systems, require different code, etc. What may be possible on one may not be possible on the other.