# Access site Meta

Tags: support, meta, ios-app

How do you access the site meta from the iOS app? I didn't see it in the menu, or in the list of sites in the menu bar. Is this not implemented yet?

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221022/cant-get-to-per-site-metas-from-the-ios-app