# Add per-site metas to 'more' menu in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, per-site-meta

[This question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221022/233816) asked to make per-site metas more accessible, from which, updates were made to make the searching more clear, and allow a user to add them to their sites list.

This still requires manual user input however. Could a link to the per-site metas be added to the remarkably empty looking 'more' menu? I'd see it as fitting quite well alongside a link to your per-site profile.

[image: more menu]

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm, same problem, but different, more technically feasible solution!

Comment: You suggest a possible way to implement the other feature request, still dupe in my opinion.